# MySQL & PHP - select/option lists and showing data to users that still allows me to generate queries

Tags: php, mysql, forms, hidden-field

Sorry for the unclear title, an example will clear things up:

```
TABLE: Scenario_victories

ID  scenid        timestamp      userid side    playdate
1   RtBr001   2010-03-15 17:13:36   7     1     2010-03-10
2   RtBr001   2010-03-15 17:13:36   7     1     2010-03-10
3   RtBr001   2010-03-15 17:13:51   7     2     2010-03-10
```

`ID` and `timestamp` are auto-insertions by the database when the other 4 fields are added.

The first thing to note is that a user can record multiple playings of the same scenario (scenid) on the same date (playdate) possibly with the same outcome (side = winner). Hence the need for the unique ID and timestamps for good measure.

Now, on their user page, I'm displaying their recorded play history in a `<select><option>...` list form with 2 buttons at the end - `Delete Record` and `Go to Scenario`

My script takes the `scenid` and after hitting a few other tables returns with something more user-friendly like:

```
  (playdate)   (from scenid)        (from side)
#########################################################
# 2010-03-10  Road to Berlin #1 -- Germany, Hungary won #
# 2010-03-10  Road to Berlin #1 -- Germany, Hungary won #
# 2010-03-10  Road to Berlin #1 -- Soviet Union won     #
#########################################################
     [Delete Record]              [Go To Scenario]
```

in HTML:

```
<select name="history" size=3>
  <option>2010-03-10  Road to Berlin #1 -- Germany, Hungary won</option>
  <option>2010-03-10  Road to Berlin #1 -- Germany, Hungary won</option>
  <option>2010-03-10  Road to Berlin #1 -- Soviet Union won</option>
</select>
```

Now, if you were to highlight the first record and click `Go to Scenario` there is enough information there for me to parse it and produce the exact scenario you want to see. However, if you were to select `Delete Record` there is not - I have the `playdate` and I can parse the `scenid` and `side` from what's listed, but in this example all three records would have the same result.

I appear to have painted myself into a corner. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can get some unique identifying data (`ID` and/or `timestamp`) to ride along on this form without showing it to the user?

PHP-only please, I must be NoScript compliant!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a `value` attribute on your options, and make it contain the `ID` *(which is unique)* of your data :

```
<select name="history" size=3>
  <option value="1">2010-03-10  Road to Berlin #1 -- Germany, Hungary won</option>
  <option value="2">2010-03-10  Road to Berlin #1 -- Germany, Hungary won</option>
  <option value="3">2010-03-10  Road to Berlin #1 -- Soviet Union won</option>
</select>
```

Then, when receiving the data that's been posted, `$_POST['history']` will contain the `ID` that correspond to the entry choosen by the user.

And, as this `ID` is unique, you can use to identify, without any doubt, your data.

The content of the `value` attribute, when set, is passed to the server when the form is submitted -- it's not displayed to the user.

When no `value` is set for an option, the browser will pass the content of that option to the server, when the form is submitted -- which is what you were getting.

As a sidenote : as with everything submitted from a user, you must check that the value received for `$_POST['history']` is valid, safe, and all that -- it should be an integer, it should be one one the values the user can access, ...

Comment: Pascal to the rescue, yet again! Please don't tell my mama I forgot basic HTML! :-)

Comment: Hello, is that Mrs Heath? I hope you're sitting down because I have some very bad news ...